# If a cell is blank, hide next n rows, VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hide, rows

In a worksheet, "Scenarios," I'm trying to hide groups of entire rows based on whether or not the cell value in column B for that group of rows is contains the text "not included". For instance, in the range B19:B77, I have sections for accounts in each 5 rows. The first row in each section has either the account name or "not included." If it says "not included," I would like to hide that row and the subsequent 4 rows (e.g. rows 19 through 23). I am aware of how to hide entire rows based on the value of a cell (code below), but I'd like to figure out how to hide the additional rows.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each xRg In Range("B19:B77")
            If xRg.Value = "" Then
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next xRg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help, in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `For` loop could look something like:

```
Dim r As Long
For r = 19 To 77 Step 5
    Rows(r & ":" r + 4).Hidden = Cells(r, "B").Value = "not included"
Next
```

Note: That `77` looks strange.  If everything is in groups of 5 rows, your last "account name" will be in row 74, which means the last group seems to only be 4 rows (74 to 77).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!! I only modified slightly:

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
        Dim r As Long
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
              For r = 19 To 73 Step 5
        Rows(r & ":" & r + 4).Hidden = Cells(r, "B").Value = "not included"
        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub

Comment: I'd prefer `Rows(r).Resize(5).Hidden = Cells(r, "B").Value = "not included" but this works +1

Comment: @ThomasInzina I thought of doing `Resize` on `Rows`, but wasn't sure it would work, and I knew specifying the row numbers as a string would work, so I went the path of least resistance (or, rather, least effort) and used the method that wouldn't require me testing anything :D

Comment: @ThomasInzina But now you have me intrigued - what happens if you do a `Rows(10).Resize(4,12).Address`?  Hmm - time to play.  Ahh - it just grabs the first 12 columns of the 4 rows.  Seems reasonable. :)

Comment: `Rows` returns a collection of all the cells in the rows.  As soon as you Resize a Row using the ColumnSize parameter you target the first cell in the collection.  Your example returns `A10:L13`.  Of course `Rows(10).Resize(4,12 ).EntireRow.Address` will extend the selection to return all the cells in rows targeted -> `10:13`